# compare a audio file (edited) to a video file (not edited) and remove the difference in python

Tags: audio, video, compare, difference

I am very new to python programming
I am suck at this problem kindly help

I have so much data from recorded audios and videos

audios and videos are recorded in the same environment at the same time.

someone only edited the audio files and removed all the mistakes from them. but video files are not edited I want this this code to remove the difference (mistakes present in video file) between them and its not working.
code:

```
import numpy as np
import soundfile as sf
import moviepy.editor as mp

def remove_difference(audio_file, video_file):
    # read audio file
    data1, rate1 = sf.read(audio_file, dtype='int16')

    # get audio data from video file
    video = mp.VideoFileClip(video_file)
    audio = video.audio
    data2, rate2 = sf.read(audio.fps==rate1)

    # ensure audio files have same sample rate and same length
    if rate1 != rate2:
        raise ValueError("Sample rates of audio files do not match")
    if data1.shape[0] != data2.shape[0]:
        min_length = min(data1.shape[0], data2.shape[0])
        data1 = data1[:min_length]
        data2 = data2[:min_length]
    # calculate difference between audio files
    difference = data1 - data2

    # remove difference from audio1
    data1 = data1 - difference

    # create a new video clip with the modified audio
    new_audio = mp.AudioClip(data1, fps=rate1)
    final_video = mp.VideoClip(lambda t: video.get_frame(t), audio=new_audio)

    # save new video file
    final_video.write_videofile("output.mp4", fps=video.fps)

# example usage
remove_difference("audio1.wav", "video2.mp4")
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to also decode the video's audio into PCM then compare the byte (Array) values one-by-on using a For-loop...  example: check for NOT Equal to know there is a difference at this point _eg:_ `video_sound[ i ] != audioFile[ i ]` where `i` is your For-loop Index...

Comment: **(1)** Get a tool like MediaInfo or VLC media player and check the audio settings of your WAV. **(2)** Extract audio from video using a tool (eg: FFmpeg or some online extractor). Extract as PCM codec (it goes inside a WAV file) with same settings (sampleRate, num_of_Channels, etc). **(3)** Now load both WAV files into Arrays inside Python and use the For loop to compare Array values